# How to avoid repeating same words in a conversation

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, repetition

Sorry if there's an answer for my question. 

 
Is it possible to avoid of repeating the verb meaning the same thing in a conversation? 

**Example**: 
1. What do you like? 
2. I like pizza. What do you like? 
1. I like pasta.

*The word **like** is repeated four times*, and it doesn't look well. And I don't believe the sentence *I, pasta* is correct.

So.. Is there a resolution for my question? 
Thank you

Comment: Choice of verb in a dialog is usually set by the primary question.  Are there other verbs that could be used? Yes, but it is common to respond to a question with the same verb.  However, the second respondent could have used a different verb in their question, such as "What is your favorite?".  But, dialog usually follows with the same back and forth verb.

Comment: 'doesn't look _well_' indicates a bad search. (possibly a hyper-correction?)

Comment: To avoid repetition in dialog, a one-word answer is often given.  In this example, the last answer might have been simply "Pasta."

Comment: If, after answering, you wish to return a question about your experience, feelings, etc, you could ask "And you?" or, less formally, "What about you?" - this would work for "How are you?", "What kind of soup do you like?", "Have you had a good day?", etc.

Comment: @rattler - "doesn't look well" is acceptable, in British English, although it tends to be used of human actions where there is a suggestion of disreputability, e.g. it wouldn't look well for you to marry your niece.

Comment: Your new hat looks well on you; your newly painted house looks well.

Comment: "Pasta's my favorite.  How about you?"  "I like it too."

Comment: Me? Pasta. Definitely.

Comment: Style advice, in this case more suitable on 'Interpersonal Skills'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a definite formula to follow here, but a conversation like the one you've given as an example could be spoken as:

> 1. What do you like?
> 2. Pizza. You?
> 3. Pasta.

There are too many variables to be able to help in a general sense, but in order to avoid repeating the same word, use a different word or rewrite to remove the word entirely.

Answer (score 0):

That's not many *likes*. I hear people say things like:

"The dude was like, 'Back off!' and I'm like, 'Like, chill, dude,' and, like, he goes, like, postal on me . . . ."

But to answer your question, you can avoid over-using words by building your vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

A better example of how English is often really spoken:

Person 1: I'd really like to go out for dinner!
Person 2: Would you?
Person 1: Yes, I would, what about you?
Person 2: Well, I wanted to last night, not tonight.
Person 1: Yesterday?? What about the night before?
Person 2: Yeah, I wanted to but didn't.
Person 1: You didn't? Why not?
Person 2: Because if I had, you wouldn't have.
Person 1: That's not true, I would've if you'd 've said something. But you didn't.
Person 2: Yeah, that's because whenever I've said anything, you haven't wanted to, have you?
Person 1: That's not fair. I've wanted to. just to be nice....

And pizza? Forgedabout it.

Auxiliaries is *where it's at* (slang) in English conversations, typically.